# Livestock vs frozen food for interplanetary travel to Saturn's moon

Tags: space-colonization, survival, food

Set in the year 2216 C.E.

Imagine a spacecraft with a crew of twenty is leaving for Enceladus, moon of Saturn which is estimated 1.272 billions km away in a matter of months using the next generation super energy efficient ion drive capable of reaching the destination within 3 months.

How can the crews ensure they could survive throughout the journey with either livestock or frozen food?

Note: The most economic solution wins meaning try to save on fuel too and BTW all my crews are allergic to potato. Ignore the spacecraft trajectory for now, it is going to rely on Jupiter gravitational assist but not retracing Cassini's route.

Comment: Please don't use mph for space travel. The most commonly used unit for velocity in space travel is km/s, with m/s a close second depending on the values. For imperial units, ft/s is also used semi-regularly. You almost never see mph, because it's just not a very handy quantity. *Especially don't mix SI and imperial units.* 500,000 miles per hour is about 224 km/s, *or* 1.3e9 km is about 7.9e8 miles. Also, if you want to be truly accurate, you have to specify the frame of reference in which that velocity is measured; is it Sun-centric, Earth-centric, inertial (huh??), or what?

Comment: If you're trying to save on fuel, frozen food is probably not your best option. Even at a fairly conservative 3lb/person/day, that's roughly a million pounds of dead weight added to the ship. The good news is that if your drive can reach 500k mph, you should be there *much* quicker than 50 years, since you'd only need to average ~1700 mph to get there in that amount of time (unless my math is off). At max speed it would only take around 65 *days*, so add some time to that for accel/decel, but not fifty *years*.

Comment: See also [Why does a spacecraft use a curved orbit to go to its destination, instead of traveling in a straight line?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/7981/415) for a discussion of why you can't use a trivial "straight line" path for calculating distance covered in spaceflight. Also, while I haven't run the numbers on your particular engine design, you may find [Constant acceleration Rockets](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/4001/415) useful.

Comment: @MichaelKjörling: I'll amend it later currently busy poking my calculator buttons...

Comment: If it is only 200 years in the future, how do they know people will live for 600 years?  It might seem like it, but they might suddenly crash at 400 years...

Comment: @Xavon_Wrentaile: this is an expected longevity for human in the year 2216, of course statistic may prove otherwise.

Answer (score 4):

"Livestock" is a terrible idea, because you have to account for the food and water necessary for *them* to survive as long as they do, and it's much more efficient to get the calories and nutrients directly from plants than via animals.

If it's a short-term mission, you can save a considerable amount on space and mass by stocking *dehydrated* food; after all, most forms of food are over 50% water by weight. (Food shipped up to the International Space Station is dehydrated.) You're going to have to institute water recycling anyway, after all. Both Mir and the International Space Station have, on occasion, gone [six months or more between resupply missions](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/2014/whats-the-maximum-amount-of-time-the-iss-can-go-between-resupply-runs), which shows you what is possible with today's technology.

If it's a long mission and you want to save on mass and thus fuel, then you need to recycle *everything*, which means simplified (but high-efficiency) agriculture to recycle human wastes, probably something hydroponic with genetically engineered plants. (For short missions, the extra mass of the agricultural system might outweigh dehydrated food.)

Answer (score 0):

If we can survive 600 years, humanity will have discovered lots of really powerful biotech. With that they could make humans who can hibernate for years at a stretch, and humans who can freeze solid without cell damage. Those are the most efficient. If your passengers want to be alive, this level of biotech would allow them to grow stem cell meat for sure, and almost certainly have engineered micro organisms which can grow on primitive feedstocks and self-assemble into nearly any flavor or texture.

Comment: Hi I removed the longevity so perhaps you may need to make changes in your answer. Sorry for any inconveniences.